# Syntax errors detected : syntax error, unexpected 'error' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' (Line 324)

Tags: php

soy nuevo en esto de la programación :( y he obtenido el error:

> Syntax errors detected : syntax error, unexpected 'error' (T_STRING),
> expecting ',' or ';' (Line 324)

y al pasarlo en un verificador de PHP sale que este es el fragmento erróneo:
[(ACA EN PASTEBIN, CON LAS LINEAS Y TODO BIEN CLARO)](https://pastebin.com/KxKnRkD4)

```
<?php $ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["kbxsfmnyjowo"] = "cctype";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xnxvmrifppt"] = "rand";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["tubgpxsbfewq"] = "ccklas";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xddhffwqqof"] = "ccbrand";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xgtiquqfje"] = "namabnk";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["wxrkwzloe"] = "getbank";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["lfbquttl"] = "jeniscc";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["rhvuunpvp"] = "bin";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["wozbundy"] = "format";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["qkamxur"] = "expy";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["olhrcngbwr"] = "expm";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["kvsoxwwewik"] = "num";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["pkdjsrgoeod"] = "datas";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["rtakzeg"] = "data";
$ {
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["rtakzeg"]
} = $_POST["data"];
if (!empty($_POST["data"])) {
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["tifvslhbsu"] = "expy";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["jesxnlllggy"] = "data";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["oqiiij"] = "datas";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["seargyf"] = "datas";
    $cohssrfjye = "expm";
    preg_match("#^[\d]{16}\|[\d]{2}\|[\d]{4}\|[\d]{3}\$#", $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["jesxnlllggy"]
    }, $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["seargyf"]
    });
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    } = explode("|", $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    }
    [0]);
    $miakmmpzglv = "datas";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["kdfpzwmj"] = "datas";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kvsoxwwewik"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    }
    [0];
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["txsjiqnnf"] = "expy";
    $yepgerkhboxc = "cvv";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["olhrcngbwr"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kdfpzwmj"]
    }
    [1];
    $kheclh = "cvv";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["qkamxur"]
    } = $ {
        $miakmmpzglv
    }
    [2];
    $ {
        $kheclh
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["oqiiij"]
    }
    [3];
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["wozbundy"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kvsoxwwewik"]
    } . "|" . $ {
        $cohssrfjye
    } . "|" . $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["txsjiqnnf"]
    } . "|" . $ {
        $yepgerkhboxc
    };
    if ($ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["tifvslhbsu"]
    } >= 2017 && $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["olhrcngbwr"]
    } <= 12) {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["vjyzquqfef"] = "getbank";
        $xknuxrz = "bin";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["rhvuunpvp"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["kvsoxwwewik"]
        };
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["fcnommcv"] = "rand";
        $aygehjeyype = "bin";
        $qmnjgkftwxr = "rand";
        $ {
            $xknuxrz
        } = substr($ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["rhvuunpvp"]
        }, 0, 6);
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["zhqqdmvbohj"] = "rand";
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["akksmls"] = "namabnk";
        $qovsrjkj = "bin";
        $jeenvfvi = "jeniscc";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["vjyzquqfef"]
        } = explode($ {
            $aygehjeyype
        }, file_get_contents("http://bins.pro/search?action=searchbins&bins=" . $ {
            $qovsrjkj
        } . "&bank=&country="));
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        } = explode("</td><td>", $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["wxrkwzloe"]
        }
        [2]);
        $ysiynzefgq = "cctype";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xgtiquqfje"]
        } = explode("</td></tr>", $ {
            $jeenvfvi
        }
        [5]);
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["uskmrjs"] = "rand";
        $stmsvel = "ccbank";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xddhffwqqof"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [2];
        $ {
            $stmsvel
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["akksmls"]
        }
        [0];
        $ {
            $ysiynzefgq
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [3];
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["tubgpxsbfewq"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [4];
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xnxvmrifppt"]
        } = rand(1, 5);
        if ($ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["uskmrjs"]
        } == 1) {
            $jntqyrt = "ccbrand";
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["agnjkdaem"] = "ccbank";
            echo "{"error\":1,\"msg\":" < div > < bstyle = 'color:#008000;' > Live < / b > | ".${${"GLOBALS"}["wozbundy"]}."[BIN: < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ".${$jntqyrt}." < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ".${${"GLOBALS"}["agnjkdaem"]}." < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ".${${"GLOBALS"}["kbxsfmnyjowo"]}." < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ".${${"GLOBALS"}["tubgpxsbfewq"]}." < / b > ]$0.5Checked - Shinji < / div > "}";
            } elseif ($ {
                $qmnjgkftwxr
            } == 2) {
                echo "{\"error\":2,"msg":" < div > < bstyle = 'color:#FF0000;' > Die < / b > | ".${${"GLOBALS"}["wozbundy"]}."[GATE:
                    01]@ / Checked - Shinji < / div > \"}";
                } elseif ($ {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["fcnommcv"]
                } == 3) {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["anoldwe"] = "format";
                    echo "{"error\":3,\"msg\":\"<div><b style='color:#800080;'>Unknown</b> | " . $ {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["anoldwe"]
                    } . " | [GATE:01] @/ChkNET-ID</div>\"}";
                } elseif ($ {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["zhqqdmvbohj"]
                } == 4) {
                    echo "{"error\":2,\"msg\":" < div > < bstyle = 'color:#FF0000;' > Die < / b > | ".${${"GLOBALS"}["wozbundy"]}."[GATE:
                        01]@ / ChkNET - ID < / div > "}";
                    } elseif ($ {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["xnxvmrifppt"]
                    } == 5) {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["linqbcgja"] = "format";
                        echo "{"error\":3,\"msg\":\"<div><b style='color:#800080;'>Unknown</b> | " . $ {
                            $ {
                                "GLOBALS"
                            }
                            ["linqbcgja"]
                        } . " | [GATE:01] @/ChkNET-ID</div>"
                    }
                    ";}}else{$qrblsuynnj = "format";
                    echo "{"error\":4,\"msg":
                        "<b>Check the validity of a credit card</b> | " . ${$qrblsuynnj} . " [GATE:01] @/Checked - Shinji"}";
                    }
                }
?>
```

El problema parece ser de las comillas o algo así leí en un foro, de verdad se me hace super confuso todo esto y es por ello que requiero ayuda, ya he puesto todo el código que alguien pidió, espero sea suficiente para explicar a detalle mi problema :"/
Esto paso al desencriptar el código php que alguien me proporciono XD

Comment: Yo soy nuevo en esto de la adivinación, disculpa que no sea capaz de arreglar un error sin ver el código entero donde está dando dicho error. Si quieres evitar que tu pregunta acabe cerrada edítala para añadir todo el código que pueda estar relacionado con el error. Debes darnos un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ver el error, no somos adivinos!

Comment: Una disculpa, lo he corregido. puedes darle un vistazo? @Benito-B

Comment: Mucho codigo para encontrar la aguja en el pajar, prueba ir agregando segmentos de codigo para descubrir en que segmento esta la falla, si parece una falla de semantica, alguna coma omitida y PHP salta a la linea siguiente

Comment: Parece que es en la ejecucion del echo, puedes probar depurando esa cadena de texto por aparte

Comment: De verdad soy muy novato y no te he entendido nada ;( podrias ayudarme mas? @AugustoM

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KxKnRkD4 mira @AugustoM aca esta el codigo con las lineas y todo para que te sea mas facil verlo

Comment: Hay muchos errores de sintaxis en las cadenas creadas, comillas sin escapar dentro de cadenas  (`"` en vez de (`\"`) en muchos lugares. Corrige eso y el codigo deberia funcionar (ejemplo: `echo "{"error\"` debe ser `echo "{\"error\"`

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores en el código, no sólo en la línea 324. Se trata de errores de concatenación entre variables, strings y también, como te comenta @AugustoM, problemas con las comillas.

Prueba a sustuirlo por lo siguiente:

```
<?php $ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["kbxsfmnyjowo"] = "cctype";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xnxvmrifppt"] = "rand";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["tubgpxsbfewq"] = "ccklas";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xddhffwqqof"] = "ccbrand";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["xgtiquqfje"] = "namabnk";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["wxrkwzloe"] = "getbank";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["lfbquttl"] = "jeniscc";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["rhvuunpvp"] = "bin";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["wozbundy"] = "format";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["qkamxur"] = "expy";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["olhrcngbwr"] = "expm";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["kvsoxwwewik"] = "num";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["pkdjsrgoeod"] = "datas";
$ {
    "GLOBALS"
}
["rtakzeg"] = "data";
$ {
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["rtakzeg"]
} = $_POST["data"];
if (!empty($_POST["data"])) {
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["tifvslhbsu"] = "expy";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["jesxnlllggy"] = "data";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["oqiiij"] = "datas";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["seargyf"] = "datas";
    $cohssrfjye = "expm";
    preg_match("#^[\d]{16}\|[\d]{2}\|[\d]{4}\|[\d]{3}\$#", $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["jesxnlllggy"]
    }, $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["seargyf"]
    });
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    } = explode("|", $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    }
    [0]);
    $miakmmpzglv = "datas";
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["kdfpzwmj"] = "datas";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kvsoxwwewik"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["pkdjsrgoeod"]
    }
    [0];
    $ {
        "GLOBALS"
    }
    ["txsjiqnnf"] = "expy";
    $yepgerkhboxc = "cvv";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["olhrcngbwr"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kdfpzwmj"]
    }
    [1];
    $kheclh = "cvv";
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["qkamxur"]
    } = $ {
        $miakmmpzglv
    }
    [2];
    $ {
        $kheclh
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["oqiiij"]
    }
    [3];
    $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["wozbundy"]
    } = $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["kvsoxwwewik"]
    } . "|" . $ {
        $cohssrfjye
    } . "|" . $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["txsjiqnnf"]
    } . "|" . $ {
        $yepgerkhboxc
    };
    if ($ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["tifvslhbsu"]
    } >= 2017 && $ {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["olhrcngbwr"]
    } <= 12) {
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["vjyzquqfef"] = "getbank";
        $xknuxrz = "bin";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["rhvuunpvp"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["kvsoxwwewik"]
        };
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["fcnommcv"] = "rand";
        $aygehjeyype = "bin";
        $qmnjgkftwxr = "rand";
        $ {
            $xknuxrz
        } = substr($ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["rhvuunpvp"]
        }, 0, 6);
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["zhqqdmvbohj"] = "rand";
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["akksmls"] = "namabnk";
        $qovsrjkj = "bin";
        $jeenvfvi = "jeniscc";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["vjyzquqfef"]
        } = explode($ {
            $aygehjeyype
        }, file_get_contents("http://bins.pro/search?action=searchbins&bins=" . $ {
            $qovsrjkj
        } . "&bank=&country="));
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        } = explode("</td><td>", $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["wxrkwzloe"]
        }
        [2]);
        $ysiynzefgq = "cctype";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xgtiquqfje"]
        } = explode("</td></tr>", $ {
            $jeenvfvi
        }
        [5]);
        $ {
            "GLOBALS"
        }
        ["uskmrjs"] = "rand";
        $stmsvel = "ccbank";
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xddhffwqqof"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [2];
        $ {
            $stmsvel
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["akksmls"]
        }
        [0];
        $ {
            $ysiynzefgq
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [3];
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["tubgpxsbfewq"]
        } = $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["lfbquttl"]
        }
        [4];
        $ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["xnxvmrifppt"]
        } = rand(1, 5);
        if ($ {
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["uskmrjs"]
        } == 1) {
            $jntqyrt = "ccbrand";
            $ {
                "GLOBALS"
            }
            ["agnjkdaem"] = "ccbank";
            echo "{error:1,msg: < div > < bstyle = 'color:#008000;' > Live < / b > | ${${'GLOBALS'}['wozbundy']} [BIN: < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ${$jntqyrt} < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ${${'GLOBALS'}['agnjkdaem']} < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ${${'GLOBALS'}['kbxsfmnyjowo']} < / b > < bstyle = 'color:red;' > - < / b > < bstyle = 'color:blue;' > ${${'GLOBALS'}['tubgpxsbfewq']} < / b > ]$0.5Checked - Shinji < / div > }";
            } elseif ($ {
                $qmnjgkftwxr
            } == 2) {
                echo "{error:2,msg: < div > < bstyle = 'color:#FF0000;' > Die < / b > | ${${'GLOBALS'}['wozbundy']} [GATE:01]@ / Checked - Shinji < / div > }";
                } elseif ($ {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["fcnommcv"]
                } == 3) {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["anoldwe"] = "format";
                    echo "error:3,msg:<div><b style='color:#800080;'>Unknown</b> | " . $ {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["anoldwe"]
                    } . " | [GATE:01] @/ChkNET-ID</div>\"}";
                } elseif ($ {
                    $ {
                        "GLOBALS"
                    }
                    ["zhqqdmvbohj"]
                } == 4) {
                    echo "error:2,msg: < div > < bstyle = 'color:#FF0000;' > Die < / b > | ${${'GLOBALS'}['wozbundy']} [GATE:01]@ / ChkNET - ID < / div > }";
                    } elseif ($ {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["xnxvmrifppt"]
                    } == 5) {
                        $ {
                            "GLOBALS"
                        }
                        ["linqbcgja"] = "format";
                        echo "{error:3,msg:<div><b style='color:#800080;'>Unknown</b> |  $ {${'GLOBALS'} ['linqbcgja']}  | [GATE:01] @/ChkNET-ID</div>}";}}else{$qrblsuynnj = "format";
                        echo "{error:4,msg:<b>Check the validity of a credit card</b> |  ${$qrblsuynnj} [GATE:01] @/Checked - Shinji}";
                    }
                }
?>
```

Comment: @YaelOsoXD, lo siento pero en el código que me pasas en el link es completamente imposible poder hacer debug y ver que error(es) hay. Que error te da con el código que te he pasado?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el código es "api.php" y el index es en pocas palabras un checker, si el "api.php" se queda tal cual encriptado, la web funciona, entonces intenté reemplazar el código encriptado del api.php al código que me has dado, pero no funciona la web, el proceso no inicia :'/

Comment: El código tal vez esté encriptado porque generar tarjetas de crédito falsas es ilegal, y pedir ayuda para hacer funcionar ese código puede meter en problemas a la gente.